# Difference between update(other_hash) and merge(other_hash)

Tags: ruby

***Update Code:***

```
irb(main):001:0> h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
irb(main):002:0> h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
=> {"b"=>254, "c"=>300}
irb(main):003:0> h1.update(h2)
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
```

**Merge Code:**

```
irb(main):001:0> h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
irb(main):002:0> h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
=> {"b"=>254, "c"=>300}
irb(main):003:0> h1.merge(h2)
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
irb(main):004:0>
```

I ran the above `merge` and `update` method on the same `hash`. But got the same output. So here my question is: are `update` and `merge` works with same logic? if not same then how the output came same for those?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Are `update` and `merge` works with same logic?

No, they are not the same. [`update` is an alias for `merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-update), which is the in-place variant of `merge`.

> if not same then how the output came same for those?

Because in both cases you are using the return value of the call, however, the value of `h1` is different in each case:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.update(h2)
h1  #=> { "a" => 100, "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }

h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge(h2)
h1  #=> { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
```

Comment: `h1.update(h2)`  and  `h1.merge!(h2)` are same i just tested.

Answer (score 3):

`Hash#update` is an alias for `Hash#merge!`
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-update

Comment: Actually it's an alias for `merge!` which updates the current hash, `merge` returns a copy

Comment: @aromero Of course, without your edit, the original answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall it's just a bang, feel free to revert the changes

Answer (score 2):

Hash#update is alias to Hash#merge!

The difference between Hash#merge and Hash#update is Hash#update updates keys/values **in-place**, whereas Hash#merge **returns** updated hash without touching the calling instance.

Answer (score 1):

h1.update(h2) - updates h1 instance - returns updated h1;
h1.merge(h2) - leaves h1 and creates updated copy - returns a updated copy of h1 (h3 I could call it)