# My Inner Hash is replacing the existing value when I assign a new value

Tags: ruby

I am storing the result in hash like this

I have assigned the result like this

```
Result['UserCreation']={"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan"}
```

So it created the hash like this

```
{"UserCreation"=>{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan"}}
```

Now, I don't know how to assign another result for Test2. When I tend to assign result like this

```
Result['UserCreation']={"Test2"=>"Kali"}
```

It's replacing the existing result, and it's correctly doing it's Job, but I want to create result hash like given below when I assign the Result of Test2

```
{"UserCreation"=>{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan","Test2"=>"Kali"}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Let us assume in this order I receive parameters

```
'UserCreation',{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan"},
'UserCreation',{"Test2"=>"Kali"}
'contactcreate',{"Test2"=>"Kali"}
```

Result

```
{"UserCreation"=>{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan","Test2"=>"Kali"},'contactcreate'=>{"Test2"=>"Kali"}}
```

All these values are the parameter to the functions.

Comment: To answer your question completely you should post precise sequence of parameters that you receive. For example is it an array with the first element of the type and other elements as pairs, or will you receive these parameters one by one.

Comment: @Psylone Added now, you can check it out.

Comment: See the answer's update.

Comment: @Psylone I have already started using `||=` but it's still not working, I am checking whether I have made any mistake, let me update you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) method:

```
Result['UserCreation'].merge!({"Test2"=>"Kali"})
```

**Here's a brief explanation:**

When you use the assignment (`Result['UserCreation']={"Test2"=>"Kali"}`) you completely replace the value for the particular hash key. If you want to add (merge) something inside the existing hash you should use `merge!` method.

Notice that you can use `Hash#merge!` method because you know that the value of `Result['UserCreation']` is a hash itself.

Also notice that there's `merge` method without bang (`!`). The difference that bang-version will mutate (change) your object. Consider this:

```
hash = {}
hash.merge({'one' => 1})

# hash variable will hold its initial value
# because `merge` method will not change it.
p hash # => {}

hash.merge!('one' => 1)
# This time we use bang-version, so hash variable
# will be updated.
p hash # => {"one"=>1}
```

One more thing about Ruby, notice how in the bang-version we omit curly braces. It's possible to do it if the **last argument** you passing to the method is a Hash.

Also, by convention in Ruby *snake-case* is using for variable and method naming, i.e.

```
result = {}
result['user_creation'] = {'test_1' => 'Rajagopalan'}
result['user_creation'].merge!('test_2' => 'Kali')
```

Of course, there's a field to play. For example, you can set the initial value like this:

```
result = {'user_creation' => {}}
result['user_creation'].merge!('test_1' => 'Rajagopalan')
result['user_creation'].merge!('test_2' => 'Kali')
```

or event update several pairs:

```
result = {'user_creation' => {}}
result['user_creation'].merge!(
  'test_1' => 'Rajagopalan',
  'test_2' => 'Kali'
)
```

**UPDATE**

For your case if you receive these parameters:

```
'UserCreation',{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan"},
'UserCreation',{"Test2"=>"Kali"}
'contactcreate',{"Test2"=>"Kali"}
```

suppose that the first parameter named `kind` and the last one named `value`:

```
# kind = 'UserCreation' and value = '{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan"}'.
result = {}
# Here we check `result[kind]` if there's no key, a new hash will
# be assigned, otherwise the existing value will be used.
result[kind] ||= {}
result[kind].merge!(value)
```

Comment: Keep in mind difference between merge and update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307034/difference-between-updateother-hash-and-mergeother-hash

Comment: I have written this code to check it out, `Result={}

p Result['UserCreation'].merge!({"Test2"=>"Kali"})` but it's throwing this error ``<main>': undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` , Okay, I think your updates answer my question, So when I call merge function, it should already been a hash, but my requirement is it has to start with the empty hash.

Comment: That's because `Result` initially is an empty hash. So `Result['UserCreation']` will give you `nil` value. Updated the answer, please see it.

Comment: yeah, your updated answer has given me the clue. But my requirement is adding the hash value one after another from the status of empty.

Comment: After every execution, all these `'user_creation'` , `{'test_1' => 'Rajagopalan'}`  come as a parameter.

Comment: Updated the answer again, but not sure that this is exactly what you need.

Comment: First time, I will receive this `user_creation and {'test_1' => 'Rajagopalan'} `second time I will receive this `user_creation and {'test_1' => 'Kali'}` and third time I may receive something else like `contactcreation and {'test_1' => '3232'}` so I have to update one after another. you are assigning user_creation and creating the hash but that wouldn't work here.

Comment: You can do it with sequentially calls to `merge!` if you set the initial hash value like `result = {'user_creation' => {}}`.

Comment: I can't set initial hash value because that too come as a result.

Comment: Can you please post 2 sequential results that you receive?

Comment: If you get `first = {'user_creation' => {'test_1' => 'Rajagopalan'}}` and then `second = {'user_creation' => {'test_2' => 'Kali'}}`, you can do this: `result = {'user_creation' => {}}` and then merge: `result['user_creation'].merge!(first['user_creation'])` and `result['user_creation'].merge!(second['user_creation'])`.

Comment: I think this answer the question wait let me check and let you know.

Comment: Okay, it actually works, Since I am using Rspec, my before(:all) block is reinilizing the hash again and again, that's what it doesn't seems to be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use [Hash#store](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-store):

```
result = {}
result['UserCreation'] = {"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan"}

result['UserCreation'].store("Test2", "Kali")
result #=> {"UserCreation"=>{"Test1"=>"Rajagopalan", "Test2"=>"Kali"}}
```

Comment: This once again assume initial assignment.